# Вопрос по массиву объектов класса в C#

Tags: c#, массивы, классы

Здравствуйте! Я новичок в программировании. Пробую учить C#. 
Хотел сделать генерацию массива объектов класса с последующим выводом их полей на экран.

```
using System;

class Building
    {
    string street_name;
    int house_num;
    double living_square;

    public void info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Адрес: Ул. {0} д.{1} площадь:{2:#.##}",street_name,house_num,living_square);
    }
        public Building()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            street_name = "Ленина";
            house_num = rnd.Next(30);
            living_square = rnd.NextDouble()*1000;
        }
    }

class PrePostDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Building[] all_bld = new Building[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < all_bld.Length; i++)
        {
            all_bld[i] = new Building();
        }
        foreach (Building x in all_bld)
        {
            x.info();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

В конструкторе класса генерируются 2 случайных числа для полей. При запуске программы консоль выводит 5 раз информацию с одними и теми же цифрами. Хотя если я прохожусь пошагово в дебагере по коду, собирается правильный массив, и 5 раз выводитится информация с разными цифрами, как я и задумывал. Подскажите, почему так происходит? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что в конструкторе класса Random вы не задаете значение параметра seed, который определяет параметры генерации псевдослучайных чисел. В целом использовать Random без seed - затея далеко не плохая, и в большинстве случаев проблем не будет. Но в вашем случае вы используете генерацию случайных числе в цикле, при этом на каждой новой итерации создаете новый экземпляр класса Random. Так вот, вернемся к параметру seed. В случае его отсутствия (то есть при использовании конструктора по умолчанию, как вы это и делаете) начальное значение берется из системного таймера, который имеет некую определенную разрешающую способность. Так как вы инициируете Random'ы в цикле (а итерации ваших циклов проходят очень быстро, поскольку действий в них выполняется немного), то системный таймер не успевает изменить свое значение на необходимую величину, а следовательно, каждый раз новый Random инициируется одинаковыми начальными значениями, а следовательно, на выходе вы получаете одни и те же значения случайных чисел.

Отсюда несложно понять, отчего под дебагом все работает как надо, а без дебага - как не надо. Именно потому что пока вы отлаживаете, системный таймер успеваеи изменить свое значение, тогда как при непрерывном выполнении - не успевает.

Поправить ваш код можно например так:

```
public Building(int seed)
{
    Random rnd = new Random(seed);
    street_name = "Ленина";        
    house_num = rnd.Next(30);
    living_square = rnd.NextDouble() * 1000;        
}

for (int i = 0; i < all_bld.Length; i++)
{
    all_bld[i] = new Building(i);
}
```